# Prolog not a function errors

Tags: prolog

I'm a student in a class where we briefly are looking at several programming languages and have to make small programs with some of them. We are using Prolog this time. It's my first time ever with Prolog, and I am so confused (I'm used to Java or C#).

I completed the first program, but the second one we have to do says "Create a program in which P(X) is true if X is a list containing n a's followed by n b's for some integer n". (P([a, a, b, b]) would be true while P([a, b, b]) would be false).

my idea was this: P(X) will check and be sure X is a list, and that X is even (if it's an odd length, it will never be true). Then it calls another fact check "check_element" where if it is less than half way through the list, it checks for a's, if it is over half way, it checks for b's.

This is my code:

```
check_element([], len, count). %Terminate, list is empty
check_element([H|T], len, count) :- count =< len/2, H == a, 
                                        count0 is count + 1, check_element(T, len, count0);
                                        count > len/2, H == b,
                                        count0 is count + 1, check_element(T, len, count0).
p(X) :- is_list(X), length(X, len),
        mod(len/2) =:= 0, %Makes sure length is even. If odd, auto fail.
        check_element(X, len, 1).
```

I get the following errors:

Arithmetic: `count' is not a function

Arithmetic: `mod(len/2)' is not a function

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Variables in Prolog **must** be capitalized.

Comment: Couple of things right off: (1) Variables in Prolog must start with a capital letter (or `_` if they are anonymous), which will fix most of your issues, and (2) `mod` is not a function, as stated in the error message. See [SWI Prolog Arithmetic Functions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=functions).

Comment: Also, mod needs two arguments and is an operator, not a function, so you would want something like `0 =:= 2 mod Len`. You have deeper issues here; I would strongly recommend you try a Prolog tutorial before trying to write this much.

Comment: Mod isn't a function? I guess that's why it's so screwed up. Our teacher made a "Prolog intro" powerpoint, and it had Mod as a function. (She wrote "X is mod(10/3)"

Comment: What would `mod(10/3)` really mean? That kind of syntax would be unusual in any language. `mod` generall requires two arguments. Perhaps the teacher got it confused with `floor` or something like that. Fix your variables and your `mod` and see where that leads you.

Comment: Makes you wonder why people develop a negative attitude towards Prolog, what with such great teaching.

Comment: Haha, I guess in retrospect that syntax would be strange if it was real. I fixed my mod and my variables, and now I have no errors, (just a singleton variable warning). It still doesn't work, but atleast now I can focus on what may be wrong with my logic. Thanks :)

Comment: @SloanTheSloth progress! :)